# Error 1064 Mysql syntax in After Update Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have an error in my After Update Trigger. I can't figure out where I went wrong. Do you have any suggestions? The trigger is supposed to change the status of another related table (users) when I change the main table I applied my trigger (sites)

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `update_sites_contacts` AFTER UPDATE ON `sites`
FOR EACH ROW
IF NEW.is_mlgu_handled = 1 AND OLD.is_mlgu_handled != NEW.is_mlgu_handled THEN     
UPDATE commons_db.users
SET commons_db.users.status = 0
WHERE user_id in (
    SELECT user_id FROM
        commons_db.sites
        LEFT JOIN commons_db.user_organizations using (site_id)
        LEFT JOIN commons_db.users using (user_id)
        WHERE ewi_recipient = 1
        AND org_name in ('lewc','blgu','mlgu')
    );
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

Compound statements such as `IF...THEN...END IF` can only be used inside a `BEGIN...END` block.